# BigNumber/BigFraction implementation in Java

Tags: java

I have created a BigFraction alternative to [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Name for this class is not quite hammered down yet.

I recently finished a class that taught us about OOP and documentation. We learned about Preconditions and Postconditions, LSP, State Representation, and more. I built this project to show (some of) the fruits of my effort. Special attention was placed to make sure this class was well-documented, as Javadoc was a very big part of that class too.

I welcome and invite any and all input/criticism/comments/etc. Please do not pull punches or limit/exclude for brevity -- I want all feedback and intend to read every word.

Finally, here is the GitHub for it, in case the commit history assists in providing feedback. Nothing is there that hasn't been pasted here (barring some git config files and the jGRASP project containing this code).

https://github.com/davidalayachew/BigNumber

Thank you for your time and help!

---

## BigInteger.java

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Objects;

/** If you know BigInteger and BigDecimal, think of this as BigFraction. This class is immutable. */
public final class BigNumber
{

   /**
    *
    * The numerator.
    *
    * Can be any whole number.
    * Must always contain the negative symbol if the whole "BigNumber" is negative.
    * Cannot be null;
    *
    */
   private final BigInteger numerator;

   /**
    *
    * The denominator.
    *
    * Can be any whole number except for zero.
    * Must always be unsigned.
    * Cannot be null.
    *
    */
   private final BigInteger denominator;

   /**
    *
    * Constructor.
    *
    * @param param the new number.
    *
    */
   public BigNumber(long param)
   {
   
      this(BigInteger.valueOf(param), BigInteger.ONE);
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Constructor.
    *
    * @param param the new number.
    * @throws NullPointerException if parameter is null
    *
    */
   public BigNumber(BigInteger param)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(param, "parameter cannot be null");
   
      this.numerator = param;
      this.denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Constructor.
    *
    * @param numerator        the numerator.
    * @param denominator      the denominator.
    * @throws NullPointerException        if numerator or denominator is null
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException    if denominator is 0
    *
    */
   public BigNumber(BigInteger numerator, BigInteger denominator)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(numerator, "numerator cannot be null");
      Objects.requireNonNull(denominator, "denominator cannot be null");
   
      if (denominator.intValue() == 0)
      {
      
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("denominator cannot be 0");
      
      }
   
      this.numerator = isPositive(denominator) ? numerator : numerator.negate();
      this.denominator = denominator.abs();
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Constructor.
    *
    * @param param the new number.
    * @throws NullPointerException if parameter is null
    *
    */
   public BigNumber(BigNumber param)
   {
   
      this(Objects.requireNonNull(param, "BigNumber cannot be null").numerator, param.denominator);
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Returns the (signed) numerator.
    *
    * @return     the numerator.
    *
    */
   public BigInteger getNumerator()
   {
   
      return this.numerator;
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Returns the (unsigned) denominator.
    *
    * @return     the denominator.
    *
    */
   public BigInteger getDenominator()
   {
   
      return this.denominator;
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Returns an equivalent BigNumber, but with the sign changed from positive to negative, or vice versa.
    *
    * @return     a BigNumber that has had its sign flipped
    *
    */
   public BigNumber negate()
   {
   
      return this.multiply(-1);
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Returns true if positive.
    *
    * @return     the result
    *
    */
   public boolean isPositive()
   {
   
      return isPositive(this.numerator);
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Returns true if num is >0.
    *
    * @param num  the number we are checking the sign of
    * @return     boolean result
    *
    */
   private static boolean isPositive(BigInteger num)
   {
   
      return num.signum() > 0;
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Method to simplify the numerator and denominator before creating a BigNumber from them.
    *
    * Numerator cannot be null.
    * Denominator cannot be null.
    * Denominator cannot be 0.
    *
    * @param numerator     the numerator
    * @param denominator   the denominator
    * @return              the simplified BigNumber
    *
    */
   private static BigNumber simplify(BigInteger numerator, BigInteger denominator)
   {
   
      final var gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator);
   
      return new BigNumber(numerator.divide(gcd), denominator.divide(gcd));
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard add function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to add.
    * @return           The answer.
    *
    */
   public BigNumber add(long param)
   {
   
      return this.add(new BigNumber(param));
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard add function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to add.
    * @return           The answer.
    * @throws NullPointerException if parameter is null
    *
    */
   public BigNumber add(BigNumber param)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(param, "parameter cannot be null");
   
      BigInteger resultNumerator;
      BigInteger resultDenominator;
   
      if (this.denominator.equals(param.getDenominator()))
      {
      
         resultNumerator = this.numerator.add(param.getNumerator());
         resultDenominator = BigInteger.ONE;
      
      }
      
      else
      {
      
         //our goal here is to end up with a shared denominator
         //So, in order to accomplish that, we will need to do
         //that cross multiplication thing that you do to end
         //up with the same denominator
      
         BigInteger numerator1 = this.numerator.multiply(param.denominator);
         BigInteger numerator2 = param.numerator.multiply(this.denominator);
      
         resultNumerator = numerator1.add(numerator2);
         resultDenominator = param.getDenominator().multiply(this.getDenominator());
      
      }
   
      //simplify before we return. We don't want to waste memory when the number can be simplified into something smaller.
      return simplify(resultNumerator, resultDenominator);
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard subtract function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to subtract from this.
    * @return           The answer.
    *
    */
   public BigNumber subtract(long param)
   {
   
      return this.add(new BigNumber(param * -1));
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard subtract function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to subtract from this.
    * @return           The answer.
    *
    */
   public BigNumber subtract(BigNumber param)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(param, "BigNumber cannot be null");
   
      return this.add(param.negate());
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard multiply function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to multiply.
    * @return           The answer.
    *
    */
   public BigNumber multiply(long param)
   {
   
      return this.multiply(new BigNumber(param));
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard multiply function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to multiply.
    * @return           The answer.
    * @throws NullPointerException if parameter is null
    *
    */
   public BigNumber multiply(BigNumber param)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(param, "parameter cannot be null");
   
      BigInteger resultNumerator = this.numerator.multiply(param.numerator);
      BigInteger resultDenominator = this.denominator.multiply(param.denominator);
   
      return simplify(resultNumerator, resultDenominator);
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard divide function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to divide this by.
    * @return           The answer.
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if param == 0
    *
    */
   public BigNumber divide(long param)
   {
   
      if (param == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("param cannot be 0"); }
   
      return this.divide(new BigNumber(param));
   
   }

   /**
    *
    * Standard divide function.
    *
    * @param param      the number to divide this by.
    * @return           The answer.
    * @throws NullPointerException if parameter is null
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if param == 0
    *
    */
   public BigNumber divide(BigNumber param)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(param, "parameter cannot be null");
   
      if (param.numerator.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("param cannot be 0"); }
   
      return this.multiply(new BigNumber(param.denominator, param.numerator));
   
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   public String toString()
   {
   
      return this.numerator + " / " + this.denominator;
   
   }

}
```

Comment: I should mention, I forgot to clean up some imports at the top. Those are remnants from me running this class locally during testing. Edited them out.

Comment: If you have unit tests, it would be helpful if you posted them.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I do not have unit tests. Most of my testing was done ad-hoc, as my API kept changing. Let me know if you would like, and I can make a suite of tests.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Looks like the lack of unit tests led to a few bugs sneaking through. I'll be sure to include them in future posts from now.

Comment: Is there a reason you named this `BigNumber` instead of `BigFraction`?  If you have a comment "Think of this as ...", that argues strongly for a different name.

Comment: @Teepeemm well, I wanted to avoid calling it `BigFraction` because I didn't want the focus to be on the numerator and denominator. I feared that by calling it `BigFraction`, that is exactly what would happen. Really, what I wanted was to be able to create an arbitrary precision number that could handle doing traditional arithmetic with whole numbers, even if the resulting number is not whole. The best way (that I could see) to model that was a fraction, but I didn't want to necessarily tie myself to the concept of fractions. The real goal was an arbitrary precision number. Any ideas?

Comment: @Teepeemm Originally, when I was more attached to the idea of exposing the fractional bits, I planned to use a `record` to model this. But once I realized that that meant that my state was tied to my API, I realized a `record` was not a good fit for this type of problem.

Comment: You could probably extend `java.lang.Number` class (even though there's no associated primitive type) and also implement `Comparable<BigNumber>`. Simplify method could check for simplifying signs. `add` method could only simplify the `else` block.

Comment: @davidalayachew I don't see how your real goal isn't served by BigDecimal.  I agree that BigFraction focuses on the numerator and denominator, but that's what your code ends up doing.  (Also, are you intending to handle irrational numbers?)

Comment: @AleZalazar I also thought of that too. However, like you said, going from a `BigNumber` to an `int` or `long` just wasn't likely, so it felt a bit unneeded. Will try it out though!

Comment: @Teepeemm If I want to divide 1 by 3 with `BigDecimal`, I must either sacrifice arbitrary precision, or throw an exception. Here is the documentation. -- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)

Comment: I do not intend to handle irrational numbers. And if there was another way to represent arbitrary precision, I would. I actually sort of dislike the fractional part, but it is too effective to let go of.

Comment: BTW there are some radically different arbitrary precision techniques that can (surprisingly) represent irrational numbers. For example, a number can be represented as the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients (given a polynomial and an interval between two rationals to select a specific root). Or as a continued fraction, which you can [compute term by term](https://srossd.com/posts/2020-09-18-gosper-1/). Or the (IMO) slightly boring technique of working with unevaluated roots. This has nothing to do with your code of course but I thought you might be interested.

Comment: @harold I am indeed interested, ty vm! I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Terminology

> ```
> * Can be any whole number except for zero.
> * Must always be unsigned.
> * Cannot be null.
> ```

Personally I would say that it must be strictly positive. Not just because it's shorter, but I think it's more correct terminology: `BigInteger` is always signed, because that's a property of the type (it has a sign, always), but some instances of `BigInteger` are positive and that is what's required here.

That also applies to the other use of "unsigned" in another comment.

### `BigInteger.intValue()`

Note that `intValue` returns [the low 32 bits of the BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue--). If the full value was zero, then the low 32 bits are also zero of course. But there are more cases in which the low 32 bits are zero even though the full value is not, namely every non-zero multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>.

So this has a bug:

> ```
>   if (denominator.intValue() == 0)
>   {
>   
>      throw new IllegalArgumentException("denominator cannot be 0");
>   
>   }
> ```

Namely rejecting some denominators that aren't zero, but whose low 32 bits are zero. This likely won't be detected by unit tests, unless they are specifically aimed at it.

### negate

Surely there's a simpler thing to do than multiplying by -1

> ```
> public BigNumber negate()
> {
>
>     return this.multiply(-1);
>
> }
> ```

### Negating a `long` may not actually negate it

In this code:

> ```
>    public BigNumber subtract(long param)
>    {
>    
>       return this.add(new BigNumber(param * -1));
>    
>    }
> ```

There is a bug that happens only when `param == Long.MIN_VALUE`.

There are two values for which `x * -1 == x` when `x` is a `long`: 0 of course, but also `Long.MIN_VALUE`. This edge case is pretty typical to miss.

The correct thing to do is converting the value of `param` either into a `BigInteger` or straight into a `BigNumber` and then negating that.

### Adding fractions with equal denominators

> ```
>   if (this.denominator.equals(param.getDenominator()))
>   {
>   
>      resultNumerator = this.numerator.add(param.getNumerator());
>      resultDenominator = BigInteger.ONE;
>   
>   }
> ```

Consider that `1/3 + 1/3` is supposed to be `2/3`

Comment: Beautiful, ty so much! My takeaway from reading this and the above comment is that unit tests are important. That said, I don't think I would have been able to run into some of these, even with the tests. Any suggestions for being able to capture these? Maybe it would be best if I tested the edge of boundaries? For example, 1, 0, and -1 are the edges and the boundary between positive and negative. Another boundary is if I put Long.MAX_VALUE into a BigInteger, then used that, that minus 1, and that plus 1 as other significant values? Or would you go about testing another way?

Comment: And to be clear, I meant to say "capture these without knowing of them ahead of time?" -- I don't know that bugs can happen at the borders, but it makes sense to me to test the borders anyways.

Comment: @davidalayachew testing boundary values like that is generally a good idea, not necessarily sufficient, but unfortunately what *is* sufficient depends intimately on the code, so there's not that much more that I can say that would apply in general. For example, suppose an `int` was multiplied by 3 somewhere in the code, now suddenly 0x2aaaaaab is an important troublemaker..

Comment: Much appreciated. Ty for all the help

Answer (score 4):

`Param` is a bad parameter name. It's name should describe what it represents in the domain context, not what it represents in the programming language. Use "value" instead.

```
public BigNumber(BigInteger value)
```

Provide factory methods to help the user to optimize object initialization. Having a `public static BigNumber valueOf(long value)` method allows you to skip object creation for common values like zero and one and return a constant instead (see `BigInteger.ZERO` for example).

Decide whether you want the BigNumber always to be simplified or whether the user needs to ask for it, and stick to that in all operations. Right now the constructors do not simplify the resulting `BigNumber` but the mathematical operations do. This may be confusing and needs to be documented. Personally I would go with always simplifying as it allows you to optimize the above mentioned factory methods more efficiently. Always simplifying the values also simplifies the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Zero denominator should throw an `ArithmeticException`. That's what you get when you divide by zero.

Why do you provide a static `isPositive(BigNumber)` method? Providing a method that handles null gracefully would be logical, but the method does not provide that. It seems like feature creep/clutter.

I dislike splitting up if-else statements like this. They break up the chaining and make the code hard to read.

```
  }
  
  else
  {
```

You absolutely should provide an `equals` method (and the `hashCode` that comes with that).

Providing a method to create a `BigNumber` from a `double` or `BigDecimal` is a nice exercise for future. Likewise a `valueOf(String)` that can parse the output of `toString()` back to a `BigNumber` would be neat (and then you can start worrying about characters like ½ and ¾ :D ). Regarding the toString() method, should the denominator be output at all if it is `1` or if numerator is `0`?

Comment: Ty vm! This is very helpful and a lot of great info. Responding to a few of your comments. I hear you about the spacing. I am the polar opposite -- I have to hold myself back from adding even more whitespace than what I ended up pasting here. And the BigDecimal/double sounds like a good idea. The purpose of my class was to create an arbitrary precision number class that can represent any fraction. I don't know how I would take a decimal and extract that into its fractional components. Sounds like fun lol.

Comment: @davidalayachew The method for converting a decimal number to fraction is taught in school, but since I didn't pay attention during math class, I just googled it. :)

Comment: Lol, I said one thing, but meant something entirely different. What I wanted to get at was that if I turn `BigDecimal` into a `BigNumber`, then there's a chance that `BigDecimal` already truncated the number prior, and thus, I already stunted my precision unnecessarily. I wanted to maintain arbitrary precision for as long as possible, but I felt like adding `BigDecimal` variants to all of my numbers might accidentally encourage cutting precision too early. This is more of a usability hesitation rather than anything else.

Comment: To all of my methods***

Comment: @davidalayachew Please post a re-review once you have updated your code. I wrote calculator library that used fractional numbers a few years ago and I'm interested to see how you solve the same problems (unfortunately I didn't bother to upload it to gitlab and now I don't remember where the code is).

Comment: Will do, ty. I wasn't aware that re-reviews were permitted. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

- The denominator can't be zero.
  You can certainly choose to do that. You can also choose to allow the denominator to be zero. In that case, you can represent value PositiveInfinity, NegativeInfinity and NaN. You don't have to. It depends on what you're using it for, I suppose. It will make your class a little more complicated because you will have to check for a zero denominator in every method.
- public boolean isPositive()
  Why isPositive() and not isNegative() or isZero()? This is weird. All you need is a signum() method.
- It would make sense to implement the Comparable interface, as well as equals() and hashCode().

(Other things were already mentioned in the other answers)

Comment: Ty vm! Yeah, I wanted to avoid having weird values like positive infinity and whatnot, so I avoided that intentionally. But those last 2 bullets are excellent. Thank you again for all of the help.